# What are the standard eigenvalues in $\mathbb{C^2}\otimes\mathbb{C^2}$?

Tags: measurement, mathematics, technical-standards

In $\mathbb{C^2}$, we generally take $+1$ and $-1$ as the standard eigenvalues, that's what Pauli-X, Pauli-Z measurements, etc will give us.
Is there a similar standard while measuring in the Bell basis and the computational basis in $\mathbb{C^2}\otimes\mathbb{C^2}$?

Of course, the actual eigenvalues don't matter, as long as we are talking about the same resolution of identity, but I was just wondering if there was a convention.

Comment: What do you mean by C2?

Comment: @JosuEtxezarretaMartinez, C2 is complex 2D space, or the space enough to describe 1 qubit. C2*C2 is for 2 qubits.

Comment: I think need to be careful about which symbols you're using for this. I believe the convention is to use a tensor product symbol (\otimes in LaTeX) if you mean the product Hilbert space of two qubits, whereas I would read C_2 x C_2 as the space of 2 x 2 complex matrices, or what is conventionally written as C^{2 x 2}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no notion of "standard eigenvalues" for general matrices.

Some meaningful eigenvalues for 4x4 matrices are:

- {-3/2, -1/2, 1/2, 3/2} which are the possible z-projections of a spin-3/2 particle
- Instead of eigenvalues of X and Z, use the eigenvalues of the Dirac matrices, which are 4x4 matrices that are related to Pauli matrices
- Instead of eigenvalues of X and Z, use the eigenvalues of the 4x4 generalization of the Gell-Mann matrices (which themselves are 3x3 generalizations of the 2x2 Pauli matrices).
- Finally, as Neil de Beaudrap has noted in the comment, {-1,1} can also be eigenvalues for 4x4 matrices, such as the SWAP gate.

Comment: To put a fine point on it, another set of eigenvalues which are meaningful for 4x4 matrices are {-1,+1}, e.g. for  the Swap gate, or for a coherent parity measurement (where the latter is a tensor product of Pauli matrices)

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: I have added your example, and acknowledged you for the credit.